# Why isn't this Ajax script working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create a test that will give an ending result, and everything works perfectly fine except from IE11. I have no idea why it doesn't though. http://itgo.no/televalg/

Here's the code for the script which sends users through the dynamic pages.

```
var loadedobjects = ""
var rootdomain = "http://" + window.location.hostname

function ajaxpage(url, containerid) {
  var page_request = false
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // if Mozilla, Safari etc
    page_request = new XMLHttpRequest()
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // if IE
    try {
      page_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    } catch (e) {
      try {
        page_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
      } catch (e) {}
    }
  } else
    return false
  page_request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    loadpage(page_request, containerid)
  }
  page_request.open('GET', url, true)
  page_request.send(null)
}

function loadpage(page_request, containerid) {
  if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status == 200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http") == -1))
    document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML = page_request.responseText
}

function loadobjs() {
  if (!document.getElementById)
    return
  for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var file = arguments[i]
    var fileref = ""
    if (loadedobjects.indexOf(file) == -1) { //Check to see if this object has not already been added to page before proceeding
      if (file.indexOf(".js") != -1) { //If object is a js file
        fileref = document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", file);
      } else if (file.indexOf(".css") != -1) { //If object is a css file
        fileref = document.createElement("link")
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        fileref.setAttribute("href", file);
      }
    }
    if (fileref != "") {
      document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(fileref)
      loadedobjects += file + " " //Remember this object as being already added to page
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the tooltip.js:

```
var cartip=document.createElement("div") //Dynamically create tooltip element
cartip.setAttribute("id", "cartooltip")
document.body.appendChild(cartip)
var cartooltipobj=document.getElementById("cartooltip")
var rightcolumnobj=document.getElementById("rightcolumn")

function ietruebody(){
return (document.compatMode && document.compatMode!="BackCompat")? document.documentElement : document.body
}

document.getElementById("rightcolumn").onmouseover=function(){ //show tooltip
var titletext=document.getElementById("cartitle")? document.getElementById("cartitle").innerHTML : "DD Forums Archive"
cartooltipobj.innerHTML=titletext
cartooltipobj.style.left=rightcolumnobj.offsetLeft+rightcolumnobj.offsetWidth-180+"px"
cartooltipobj.style.top=rightcolumnobj.offsetTop+rightcolumnobj.offsetHeight-40+"px"
cartooltipobj.style.visibility="visible"
}

document.getElementById("rightcolumn").onmouseout=function(){ //hide tooltip
document.getElementById("cartooltip").style.visibility="hidden"
}
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Gonna need to see code

Comment: Thanks for feedback guys! Added the code.

Comment: The code never calls `ajaxpage()`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for feedback, where would i call ajaxpage()?

Comment: From whatever part of the application that needs to load a container dynamically from a URL.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not completely sure about where to put it. Updating the post with more of the code.

Comment: What is the user supposed to do that triggers loading a page with AJAX? You need to call the function from the appropriate event handler.

Comment: On your web site you have `<a href="javascript:ajaxpage('URL')">`. That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: When you try it in IE11, are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: It has nothing to do with AJAX. The problem is that clicking on the label isn't triggering a click on the link, so it's never calling `ajaxpage()` in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar thanks! I started looking at the directing and it seems like IE11 isn't fetching the href because of how it's over several divs. I'll try to work around it!